# How to place the block on the top of "second" screen using CSS?

Tags: css

**Problem**: I have the page, where first screen (regardless of the screen resolution) is completely taken by block with beautiful background and "Sign up" button at the very bottom of this block [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXpj7/1/) (it's only for mobile version of the site, but it doesn't matter in this case)

```
<div class="first-screen"> 
    <div class="about">
        <h1>Motto</h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Click here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.first-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=first screen') transparent no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;      
}
```

**Task**: I need other content on the page to be displayed right after the first screen (right now it is under the `.first-screen` because of `position: absolute;`);

**Challenge**: I need this task to be solved **without any JS** (I can solve it using js, but I don't want to).

Any working solutions (using `display: table, table-row, table-cell;`, flexboxes etc.) or any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Note**: it can be hacked with setting the `margin-top` for the `.second-screen`, but it isn't bulletproof at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question sounds like you have tried to bring other people on some homework assignment you've been given. Is there a good reason why you don't want to use JS?

Comment: This comment sounds like you have nothing to say on the merits. I've asked for help after hours trying, wasn't stackoverflow made for this? Regarding your question - I don't want to write hacks until I'm 100% sure it can't be avoided.

Comment: Can the styles of .first-screen be manipulated? or does that have to stay exactly as is?

Comment: @Steve yep, all styles can be updated, as long as .first-screen takes all the first screen

Comment: @MarioJVargas I've tried to use `display: table`, margin-top: 100% (on large part of mobile devices it looks good, but it's unreliable because usage of block's width in calculating percents), played with 'positions:', spent some time thinking about how flexbox can be used (came to nothing), glanced at new units (as suggested below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering navbar height is a constant I came to such solution - http://jsfiddle.net/EPFq7/1/

At first we should set html and body heights to 100%:

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Then we remove navbar bottom margin:

```css
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

And the key part is to add such styles to the .first-screen (where `52px` is the height of the navbar):

```css
.first-screen {
    height:100%;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    padding: 52px 0 0;
    margin: -52px 0 0;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So doing a little research came up with this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/1192506

which then led me to use the `vh` height percentage.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tXpj7/3/

**EDIT**

Taking the accepted example from that answer using 100% height html, body and then manipulating the heights of the navbar and the first screen. you get the same kind of result.

http://jsfiddle.net/tXpj7/6/

Comment: yeah, I've considered using vh, but new units have really bad support on mobile (not to tell it looks broken on my pc) ![screenshot](http://snag.gy/l7971.jpg) But this might help someone

Comment: I came to the similar solution (based on navbar height, which is pretty static)